# Mendelbrot Calculation Code Keeps Returning 2 for IterationCount

Tags: c#, .net, rendering, mandelbrot

I'm working on writing a Mendelbrot renderer in C# to practice multithreading, but am having an issue where my calculation code maxes out at 2 iterations. I don't really understand why since the online references I've been looking at seem to calculate it the same way as me. No matter what coordinates of pixels I provide, it always returns 2 (aside from 0,0 and 0,1).

`

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using SkiaSharp;

namespace Mandelbrot
{
    internal class Program
    {
        const int MaxIterations = 100;
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int size = 250;
            
            int[,] grid = Run(size, 0, 0, 1);
            // Console.WriteLine("Please specify a square size for the image.");
            // try
            // {
            //     Console.Write("Length: ");
            //     height = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            // }
            // catch (FormatException e)
            // {
            //     Console.WriteLine(e);
            //     throw;
            // }
            
            using (var surface = SKSurface.Create(width: size, height: size, SKColorType.Rgba8888, SKAlphaType.Premul))
            {
                SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;
                canvas.DrawColor(SKColors.Coral);

                for (int i = 0; i < grid.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < grid.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        if (grid[i, j] >= MaxIterations)
                            canvas.DrawPoint(new SKPoint(i, j), SKColors.Black);
                    }
                }
                canvas.DrawPoint(new SKPoint(250, 250), SKColors.Chartreuse);
                
                OutputImage(surface);
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine("Program successfully completed.");
        }
        
        public static int[,] Run(int size, int fromX, int fromY, int h)
        {
            int[] oulltput = new int[size * size];
            int[,] output = new int[size, size];
            
            for (int i = 0; i < output.GetLength(0); i += 1)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < output.GetLength(1); j += 1)
                {
                    float x = fromX + i * h;
                    float y = fromY + j * h;
                    output[i, j] = IterCount(x, y, MaxIterations);
                }
            }

            return output;
        }

        public static int IterCount(float constX, float constY, int maxIterations)
        {
            const float maxMagnitude = 2f;
            const float maxMagnitudeSquared = maxMagnitude * maxMagnitude;
            int i = 0;
            float x = 0.0f, y = 0.0f;
            float xSquared = 0.0f, ySquared = 0.0f;
            
            while (xSquared + ySquared <= maxMagnitudeSquared && i < maxIterations)
            {
                xSquared = x * x;
                ySquared = y * y;
                float xtmp = xSquared - ySquared + constX;
                y = 2.0f * x * y + constY;
                x = xtmp;
                i++;
            }
            return i;
        }

        private static void OutputImage(SKSurface surface)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Attempting to write .png to disk...");
            using (var image = surface.Snapshot())
            using (var data = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 80))
            using (var stream = File.OpenWrite("out.png"))
            {
                // save the data to a stream
                data.SaveTo(stream);
                Console.WriteLine("Success!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

I tried to use breakpoints and writeline statements to debug but I can't figure out where my math is going wrong. I keep getting 2 for my iteration count.

Comment: It's spelled **Mandelbrot**. Your algorithm works: `IterCount((float)-0.168, (float)0.65, 100) -> 100`. There's no reason to use `float`, you are introducing error for no reason, use `double` instead. Probably you are making a mistake in your `Run` method passing large "pixel" values in. Checkout any Mandelbrot explorer application, you will see area of interest is restricted to ~ (-2,-1.5) to (0.5, 1.5).

Comment: @BurnsBA Implemented both your suggestions and it now works! Thank you. Code is here for anyone looking: https://github.com/Kakapio/mandelbrot